# Zombicide Black Plague Intro game board blocked?

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

My friends and I were playing the tutorial mission. We hit a wall (literally) when we were trying to move and couldn't find on the map where the entrance to the "2nd half" of the map was. It looks like that all of the walls are sealed off.

I'm sure that we are missing something super simple, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the example diagrams on page 36 of the [rulebook](https://zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-black-plague.pdf), multiple Vault doors of the same colour will both link to the vault of that colour.

Thus you would use the vault door on the left side of the map, enter the vault, then leave by the vault door on the right side of the map, allowing you access to the final area.

Comment: That is indeed the simple answer we were missing! Thank you!